# MySQL read lock with FOR UPDATE

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

The following assumes all statements are executed in transactions on MySQL 5.6 with an InnoDB table. Also, col1 and col2 together form a unique key.

If I do a `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = 1 AND col2 = 1 FOR UPDATE` in Session 1, I get the data from that row and an exclusive lock on that row. So if I execute that same statement on Session 2, it will wait until that lock is released before doing anything or run into a timeout. So far, so good.

Now assume the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` returns an empty set and we try to insert something in another session:

```
-- Session 1
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col1` = 1 AND `col2` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
-- Do whatever else takes some time

-- Session 2
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` SET `col1` = 1, `col2` = 1;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

This behavior is as I'd expect it. However, if we do this:

```
-- Session 1
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col1` = 1 AND `col2` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

-- Session 2
mysql> START TRANSACTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `col1` = 1 AND `col2` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `table` SET `col1` = 1, `col2` = 1;
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Now, what I actually want is that the second `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on the same (not yet existing) rows will wait in the same way an `INSERT INTO` will. How do I achieve this without locking the whole table, which would not be acceptable because other rows need to stay accessible.

Comment: I don't think it is possible what you want, since you do not have much influence over what locks are set by the sql statements. When you use innodb, then insert statement will always generate an exclusive intention lock, and select for update also requests exclusive lock.

Comment: The problem at hand is a race condition that session 1 will check with `select for update` if a specific column is already there and if not, create and save one.
Session 2 however does not see that there is going to be that row soon, since the processing takes place outside of MySQL in a php script. It can take a few miliseconds before the row is actually there. I can hack around this of course, but doing it as I stated above would be a much cleaner solution IMHO.

Comment: I understand your question, but the MySQL solution would be to use different kind of locks for the affected statements. As long as you use for update clause in you select statements, you are stuck. Obviously, if you used lock in share mode, the behaviour would be different. However, I do not know anything about your business requirements, so I do not know if this approach would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

When you let a transaction run more than a few seconds, you are asking for trouble.  Write your code to be finished quicker.  Your first code sample not `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to a ludicrously long 50 seconds.

You must write your code to catch errors -- such as the two different ones you got -- and take evasive action.  The action is usually to start the entire transaction over.  By then, the other session is likely to have finished whatever it was doing, and you should go through 'instantly'.

If you need a really long lock -- such as a shopping cart wherein a user is bouncing among web page for minutes, you must use some other mechanism for "locking", not InnoDB's transaction locking.

If you would like to further describe your application, we can discuss this further.

Comment: That was actually just me doing the process manually for illustration purposes. In the actual use-case, we are talking about two parallel processes accessing the data in the way I have shown possibly within less than a millisecond.

Comment: Was the `COMMIT` withing milliseconds?  "Do whatever else takes some time" threw me off.

Comment: Indeed, the whole process up to the commit is completed within milliseconds. The issue is that two processes will start almost at the same time but I need one of them to wait for this one row until the other process is finished.